# How to display related tables in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.5, database-relations

I've got two different tables, one is called `articles`, the other one `images` I Want to create an article that contains multiple images,

How can I create with Laravel 5.5 a many-to-many relation? I've followed this post on laracast:  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multiple-images-in-article-galerry

here is the code

ARTICLE MODEL

```
public function images() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Image');
}
```

IMAGE MODEL

```
public function articles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article'); 
}
```

ARTICLE-IMAGE MIGRATION(TABLE)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticleImageTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_image', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('image_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('images')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('article_image');
    }

}



ARTICLES CONTROLLER


<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::with('images')->get();

        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $article = Article::find($id);

        $article->load('images');

        return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
    }

}
```

MY PROBLEM IS How do i continue from here(that is display both the articles and the images)

Comment: The article on laracast contains everything you need to create a many-to-many relation. You should post your error log, the failure code or example code. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), if you edit your question it will be easier to get help.

Comment: Can you send code examples?

Comment: i have sent sample code